# How can I pause/resume download in youtube video?

Tags: video, youtube

I have downloaded youtube videos using youtube-dl. But due to network problem or other problem sometimes I am not able to download video completely. Later, I need to download that video from beginning.

Is there any way to pause and resume download? I use both Chromium and Mozilla.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can do that with `-c` option. For instance, if you previously started a download using:

```
youtube-dl <some_youtube_URL>
```

You may, if it was stopped or interrupted, resume that download later with:

```
youtube-dl -c <some_youtube_URL>
```

[image]

Comment: Will this work for resuming in the middle of a playlist (i.e. a channel)?

Comment: Yes, it does continue playlists. It will check each video and report "has already been downloaded and merged".

Answer (score 0):

**In Firefox**, You can Install **Add-ons** to Download videos. Install [Video-Download-Helper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/?src=search) and [Down-Them-All](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall/?src=search) add-ons.

There will be ***Video-Download-Helper*** icon below the video. There is a Down-Arrow button with it. click on it. There is a menu option to download with ***Down-Them-All***.

[image]

When ***Down-Them-All*** starts downloading, it **can be resumed** later.

[image]

Comment: Marked down. This answer has nothing to do with youtube-dl, which is what the question is about.

Comment: I agree. No connection between this answer and the actual question.

Comment: The question isn't purely about `youtube-dl`. The title asks how to pause and resume YouTube downloads and the question specifically allows for solutions that use Chromium or Mozilla. Nowhere does it specify that the solution needs to use `youtube-dl`.

Answer (score 0):

Find the process ID, PID, from the particular youtube-dl process that you'd like to get paused and resumed later on.

You might get that PID via `pidof youtube-dl`, `pgrep youtube-dl` or, probably even better (since one might get multiple running instances of youtube-dl), via `ps aux | grep youtube-dl | grep -v grep`.

Then utilize SIGSTOP (19) en SIGCONT (18) via the `kill` command to stop that particular PID and resume it later on.

Example;

> $ pgrep youtube-dl
> 1234

To stop/pause the process:

> $ kill -19 1234

and to resume the process:

> $ kill -18 1234

Warning: a stopped process should resume after hibernation, but not after a reboot.

To get some more information about finding a stopped process and to send a running process a SIGSTOP via control character (^Z or \x1A);

[stackoverflow.com: Linux Command to Show Stopped and Running processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859493/linux-command-to-show-stopped-and-running-processes)

[unix.stackexchange.com: If you ^Z from a process, it gets “stopped”. How do you switch back in?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109536/if-you-z-from-a-process-it-gets-stopped-how-do-you-switch-back-in)

Answer (score 0):

If someone downloading using command **youtube-dl** with extra options like:

- youtube-dl  -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]' <some_youtube_URL>

To resume download should type **-c** option with everything what was in the line:

- youtube-dl -c -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]' <some_youtube_URL>

Typing only youtube-dl <some_youtube_URL> will download the file from 0 with default parameters.